# Lyx - Missing $ inserted repeatedly

Tags: errors, lyx

I'm lost in the next problem. I am using the last version (2.0) of Lyx to write up one of my final degree projects full of maths formulas, images, drawings and tables. But at the point I'm on right off, I can't obtain the PDF version of the file. I cannot export to PDF.
I'm getting the next error continously:

```
Missing $ inserted

\maketitle

I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
```

And before that I get that next problem.

```
Package Listings error:
\lst@RequireAspects\lst@loadaspects

The following aspects weren't loadable:
,strings$,comments$,escape$,style$,language$,keywords$,labels$,lineshape$,f
rames$,emph$,index$
This may cause errors in the sequel.
```

Comment: If you're getting the `\maketitle` error followed by the `\lst...` errors, the latter may stem from the former (due to the automated insertion of `$`). You would need to supply the code up to the `\maketitle` command, perhaps via an extraction to TeX (Choose View > View Source > Complete Source).